# How to unload kernel module 'nvidia-Modeset'

Tags: debian, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to install the most up-to-date NVIDIA driver in Debian Stretch. I've downloaded NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.48.run from here, but when I try to do.

```
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.48.run
```

as suggested, an error message appears.

```
ERROR: An NVIDIA kernel module 'nvidia-modeset' appears to already be loaded in your kernel. This may be because it is in use (for example, by an X server, a CUDA program, or the NVIDIA Persistence Daemon), but this may also happen if your kernel was configured without support for module unloading. Please be sure to exit any programs that may be using the GPU(s) before attempting to upgrade your driver. If no GPU-based programs are running, you know that your kernel supports module unloading, and you still receive this message, then an error may have occured that has corrupted an NVIDIA kernel module's usage count, for which the simplest remedy is to reboot your computer.
```

Any help to finish the installation nvidia drivers?

Comment: If the answer below doesn't work, turn off persistence mode via `sudo nvidia-smi -pm 0` and now try turning off nvidia-modeset with `sudo modprobe -r nvidia-modeset` That should solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to uninstall the old driver first before you can install the new one. I don't remember if you can have the new installer remove it or do it manually.